# node-red-node-firebird returns a buffer instead of a string

Tags: buffer, firebird, node-red

I'm doing KPI's in node-red, and I'm using node-red-node-firebird to connect my database and get the results from it. For that I made a query to select the columns I need, one of those is:

NAME Varchar(40), with an example value: "Pizzas"

(example: Select NAME from mytable)

When I receive the query response on node-red, I store it inside the msg.payload. The problem is the result that I get it isn't the string "Pizzas" but a buffer "NAME":{"type":"Buffer","data":[80,105,122,122,97,115]}}.

How can I get the string and not the buffer?

I already tried a lot of things, among them:
On the query I have tried cast(NAME AS varchar(40)) AS NAME; [NAME] without success. Put msg.payload.data.toString('utf-8') in function node but nothing happens, the function:

```
var objectData = msg.objectData; //this is the query response
    
//------------Columns----------------------------
var fields = [];
var i = 0;

if(objectData.length > 0) {
   var data = objectData[0];
    for(var key in data) {
        fields[i] = key;
        i++;
    }
    
    //TRY nº1 
    objectData.foreach(function(obj){
        if (Buffer.isBuffer(obj) === true) {
          obj = obj.toString('utf-8');
        }
    })
}

//-----------------------------------------

msg.method = "POST";
msg.url = //My api request//;
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
msg.headers.Authorization = //auth//;

msg.payload = {
    'groupID': 'Group123',
    'companyID': 1221,
    'table': 'DemoTable',
    'fields': fields,
    'data': objectData, //problem 
    'delete': true,
};

//TRY nº2
msg.payload = msg.payload.data.toString('utf-8');
return msg;
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74209100/edit) the question to show the actual function node you tried, you will need to assign the value returned from `toString()` to actually use the value.

Comment: @hardillb its there now. Thank you

Comment: What is the character set of the column in the database, and what is your connection character set? I guess either or both is `NONE`, and - at a guess - the driver you're using treats NONE as octets (bytes), and thus provides the value as a buffer and not a string.

Comment: My guess seems to be confirmed by looking at the [code](https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird/blob/999f5399c32e7364c5d32fe9e1228d37b943f2a4/lib/index.js#L885) of node-firebird (which seems to be used by node-red-node-firebird), for a varchar, sub type 0 is character set `NONE` and sub type 1 is character set `OCTETS`.

Comment: Hi. I solved my problem changing the select to:
SELECT cast(name as varchar(100) character set win1252) NOME FROM mytable
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem changing the select to:

```sql
SELECT cast(name as varchar(100) character set win1252) NOME FROM mytable
```